# Install 'top' and 'find' on stripped a down debian linux with apt-get install?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation

I have a docker image I'm extending and it has a stripped down version of Debian. I've already installed some packages with the initial Dockerfile push I did but I'm also wanting to install `top` and `file` commands (already installed `htop`...). Does anyone know which packages I could install that include these with `apt-get install` that will work with Debian?

Also, I'm not sure how to find this info myself so if there is an easy way to figure it out that I could have done myself that info would be an awesome FYI to include.

Output of running `cat /etc/*-release` below:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"       
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"     
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: @zevzek The slowness of `dpkg -S` is why I originally wrote [dlocate](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/dlocate) for debian, way back in 1999.   `dlocate /usr/bin/top` takes 0.16 seconds on my threadripper 1950x (with 2 x nvme zfs mirrored root pool).  `dpkg -S /usr/bin/top` takes 1.4 seconds on the same machine.   `dlocate bin/top` works too, because it does a regex match, not an exact filename match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from the comments I came to the following answer:

I installed a debian linux vm and then ran the following commands:

```
admin:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/top
procps: /usr/bin/top
admin:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/find
findutils: /usr/bin/find
```

Then installed findutils (for find) and procps (for top) via my Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y vim \
  && apt-get install -y nano \
  && apt-get install -y curl \
  && apt-get install -y htop \
  && apt-get install -y procps \
  && apt-get install -y findutils
```